# How to synchronize two versions of NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, configuration

I have two versions of NetBeans installed (6 and 7). When installing newer version, I was asked to import old settings into it, but now the two versions are out of sync. Is there any way to synchronize open projects, libraries... at least manually by importing settings? I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

When opening the options window (menu Tools -> Options), you'll notice some button labeled "Export" that allows you to save all your settings. This will output your settings (I believe in XML format) to some zip file. You could try doing this for the older version, select what settings you wish to carry over and then importing those into the newer version.

While this would migrate your settings, I don't think it'll do anything regarding open projects or other cached stuff. You could track down where this info is stored and copy it over to the new install, but that seems risky. Overall, if possible I'd say it's best to avoid using NetBeans 6 when you've got 7 installed and removing all traces of your 6 install (minus the actual project folders, evidently).

EDIT: actually forgot to mention something important. Export all your 7 settings before attempting to import 6 settings! I advise you to do this regularly, like before installing updates or after major changes (e.g. new code templates, key shortcuts...) to have some backup in case everything goes FUBAR. Lord knows it happened to me more than once.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone checks this, copying the "config" folder between the userdir of the installations works well for me:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir

http://searjeant.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/migrating-netbeans-settings.html

Comment: Links are broken.